# executing java using php help

Tags: java, php, command-line, jar, exec

so I have the following script

```
$execStr = 'cd /D Z:\\folder'
exec($execStr);
$execStr = 'java -jar somejar.jar';
exec($execStr);
```

the jar does some operations on a mysql database...

but when I run it, it appears that the jar did not run properly because the database was unchanged

but then when I run the exact same strings from the command line it would work properly

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you combine the two `exec`'s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shell_exec('/path/to/java  -jar Z:\folder\somejar.jar');`
where you sub /path/to to the real place your java is run from.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$execStr = 'java -jar Z:\folder\somejar.jar';
shell_exec($execStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running `dir` or `ls` after your `cd` to make sure the exec environment is persisting from one command to the next.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's because when you call `java -jar ...` you're no longer in `Z:\folder` directory. Try a single command:

```
java -jar "Z:\folder\somejar.jar"
```